# Google Maps - 2 maps on the same page not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I need to have two google maps on the same page.

However, for any reason, only the first map seems to be displayed.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430076/2-google-maps-working-with-geocoding-on-same-page) topic without any success, as the problem persists.

My code now looks like this

```
function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.560655,-8.386545);
            var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.560655,-8.386545);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var mapOptions2 = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatlng2,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('room-canvas'), mapOptions2);

}
```

And the HTML

```
             <div class="g_12">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h4 class="widget_header_title wwIcon i_16_valid">Distribuição Utilizadores</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_contents noPadding" style="height:450px;">
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="g_12">
                <div class="widget_header">
                    <h4 class="widget_header_title wwIcon i_16_valid">Distribuição Salas</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_contents noPadding" style="height:450px;">
                    <div id="room-canvas"></div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF the maps DIVs are initially invisible, you must apply height style directly on that DIVs.

If it's not the case, please provide console log of 2 map objects

Comment: Life saver tip! Thank you!